# Python, position initialisation (using list) full explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a snake game and I want to start the starting position of the snake head. I bumped into this code (class constructor):

```
self.poslist = [(headposx,y) for y in reversed(range(headposy-self.length+1,headposy+1))]
```

I  want help on what this code means and what it does for me to change it to suit my already existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i see in the code you posted i can only try to explain what happens at a very technical level.

self.poslist will be a list of tuples created from the input values headposx,headposy,self.length and all the 'y' values that are in the list created by this part of code:

> reversed(range(headposy-self.length+1,headposy+1))

which is a list with all the elements specified in the range() function, taken in reverse order by the reversed() function.

So assuming, for example, this starting values for the fields

> headposy = 4
>
> headposx = 1
>
> self.length = 3

the expression will be evaluated like this:

> reversed(range(1-3+1,1+1)) => reversed(range(2,5)) => (4,3,2)
>
> (headposx,y) for y (4,3,2) => (headposx,4),(headposx,3),(headposx,2)
>
> self.poslist = [(1,4),(1,3),(1,2)]

So, for what i see, the code you posted gives the positions of the various part of the snake having in input the current head position and the length, but the x-coordinate is fixed, to this will only give you a vertical snake.

I don't know if this is what you need, but without knowing the other parts of the application i cannot help you further.